# purrr::pmap with user-defined functions and named list

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

The following piece of code works as expected:

```
library(tidyverse)
tib <- tibble(x = c(1,2), y = c(2,4), z = c(3,6)) 
tib %>% pmap(c)
#[[1]]
#x y z
#1 2 3
#
#[[2]]
#x y z
#2 4 6
```

But if I define the function

```
my_c_1 <- function(u, v, w) c(u, v, w)
```

I get an error:

```
tib %>% pmap(my_c_1)
#Error in .f(x = .l[[c(1L, i)]], y = .l[[c(2L, i)]], z = .l[[c(3L, i)]],  :
#  unused arguments (x = .l[[c(1, i)]], y = .l[[c(2, i)]], z = .l[[c(3, i)]])
```

Equivalently, for a named list with the base vector function all works well:

```
lili_1 <- list(x = list(1,2), y = list(2,4), z = list(3,6))
pmap(lili_1, c)
#[[1]]
#x y z
#1 2 3
#
#[[2]]
#x y z
#2 4 6
```

And with the user-defined function I get the same error:

```
pmap(lili_1, my_c_1)
#Error in .f(x = .l[[c(1L, i)]], y = .l[[c(2L, i)]], z = .l[[c(3L, i)]],  :
#unused arguments (x = .l[[c(1, i)]], y = .l[[c(2, i)]], z = .l[[c(3, i)]])
```

However, for an un-named list with the user-defined function, it works:

```
lili_2 <- list(list(1,2), list(2,4), list(3,6))
pmap(lili_2, my_c_1)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 2 4 6
```

I don't quite understand why things break with named lists and user-defined functions.  Any insight?

BTW, I found a temporary workaround by defining:

```
my_c_2 <- function(...) c(...)
```

Then all works well, even with named lists... which leaves me even more puzzled.
This is in the spirit of a minimal reproducible example.  In my current working code I would like to be able to pipe tibbles to pmap with my more general defined function without using the `...` workaround for my variables.

Comment: Forgot to mention I am using R version 3.4.1 with purrr_0.2.3 (on macOS Sierra 10.12.6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your function `my_c_1` has arguments `u`, `v`, `w` but you pass a list with names `x`, `y`, `z`. If you don't want a function with no named arguments (`...`, such as base's `c`), you should make sure the names match in your call.

Comment: Thanks!  Indeed it works if I define `my_c_1 <- function(x, y, z) c(x, y, z)` but that's rather inconvenient.  I might want to use that function with pmap and many different tibbles with columns not necessarily named `x`, `y`, and `z`.  Shouldn't the names of the variables in the function's definition be independent of the names of the input.  There is no such problem with map2 for example `map2(lili_1[[1]], lili_1[[2]], my_c_3)` works with `my_c_3 <- function(u, v) c(u,v)`.

Comment: it "works" with map2 because `lili_1[[1]]` doesn't have names, in which case it resorts to positional matching. It is a general feature and convention in R that named call parameters must match named arguments in a function call. If you want to rely solely on positional matching you must strip those names, or have a function with no named arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  `pmap(unname(lili_1), my_c_1)` works fine.  That's a satisfactory solution.